# Pandas Check sequence or patters

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I need to check if there is a special patter in the columns, its easier to see with some data.

[image]

now if you see there are to punch in in next to each other,
i need way to detect this patters, normally you need to clock out before you clock in
so this is a mistake from my system and i need a way to detect this on pandas. 
i was thinking using .apply(function, axis=1)

thank you in advance.
best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [pandas.DataFrame.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), this code compares the row with the next row, creating a column 'flag' when they are exactly the same:

```
comparison = df == df.shift()
df['flag'] = comparison['Date'] & comparison['Name'] & comparison['Activity']]
```

With your data, the output is:

[image]

Comment: May need to do this within each Name group